# NextJs | _ssgManifest.js, _buildManifest.js 404 and different name for file _app _#### on server build and browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, http-status-code-404

I have deployed a NextJs app on digitalocean droplet with Ubuntu 22.04.

- "next": "12.2.3",
- "react": "18.2.0",

I am getting this 404 error for **_ssgManifest.js**, **_buildManifest.js** and **_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-83b8d0a73a58c453.js** files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p5UB.png)

I checked the build on server, files are present there, but in broweser they are showing 404. Another thing I noticed that the file _app-83b8d0a73a58c453.js getting fetched on browser but on server build it is with different name i.e. _app-8ba37a8edc5ef34c.js

**What I Tried**

- I checked with and without custom dir for build, but it didn't worked
- I checked with custom buildID too

```
const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;

const lastCommitCommand = "git rev-parse HEAD";

module.exports = {
  async generateBuildId() {
    return execSync(lastCommitCommand).toString().trim();
  },
};
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you found a solution, could you share it with me? I don't think the solution below is suitable for production because the service is suspended for a while. Is there a way to resolve it without disruption?

Comment: Hi @Jay-flow, sure, I will check with site on production, and will share the solution if any other way works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a headache with the same problem 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

These files were not matching to what is asked in browser request to what is available at build on server. In my case the reason was that, after build i was not restarting the application.

if you are using pm2 to serve your application named **fe**, please run:

```
pm2 restart fe
```

Then Hard refresh your website in browser, it will work.

If you are using other tool, then please follow docs for the same to **restart** the application. And if the issue is diffrent than this in your case, please share your solution here.

Thank you.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: This method is resolved, but it is not suitable because the service is temporarily suspended for use in production. Are there other solutions for nondisruptive deployments?

Comment: Hi @cigien, thank you for the help, sure i will update it.